# Spring Data Elastic Search Nested Field and NativeSearchQueryBuilder.withFields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I can't seem to get Nested Fields to return when I use the NativeSearchQueryBuilder.withFields(...) method.

Here is my parent Object:

```
@Document(indexName = "inventory")
public class Inventory
{
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Field(type=FieldType.String)
  private String name;
  @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store=true)
  private List<Model> models;
}
```

And here is the nested Object:

```
public class Model
{
   @Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store=true)
   private String model;
   @Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store=true)
   private Set<String> series;
}
```

And the Query

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withFields("models.series");
NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
FacetedPage<Inventory> results = inventoryRepository.search(nativeSearchQuery);
```

Resulting TotalElements = 529
But each Object in the Content Looks like this (in JSON format):

```
{
   "id":"d5f82880-15bc-45ed-8abb-ff97d0e45da9",
   "name": null,
   "models": null
}
```

If I remove the withFields(...) setting, I get back:

```
{
   "id":"d5f82880-15bc-45ed-8abb-ff97d0e45da9",
   "name": "Cool Beans",
   "models": [
     {
       "model" : "foo",
       "series" : ["bar"]
     }
   ]
}
```

I've tried models, models.model, models.series, model, series. I can't get withFields working with NestedFields.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you specify `fields` in the query, it does not return the `source` in the response. Only `fields` are present in a hit to fetch your record values. I think you are looking at the source for the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of elastic search fields was incorrect. rahulroc tipped me off.

withFields is not the same as source filtering.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html

So i'm effectively telling Spring Data ES to do this:

```
curl localhost:9200/inventory/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
  "fields" : ["models.series"],
  "query" : {
     "match" : {"name" : "cool"}
  }
}'
```

When this is what I want

```
curl localhost:9200/inventory/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
  "_source" : ["models.series"],
  "query" : {
     "match" : {"name" : "cool"}
  }
}'
```

The withFields approach worked for what I was doing up till I started adding NestedFields. And the current implementation of Spring Data ES that I'm using does not support source filtering.

Source Filtering was just recently added to Spring Data ES 2.0.0.RC1